# Does it make sense to check if foreign key exists in original table?

Tags: mysql

I came across some code that I would not have written like that. However, I would not consider myself a MYSQL expert and so I am wondering if I am missing something.

For better understanding: I only want `s.SpecialID` from this query and only if there is a foreign key in my table `s` to `otherTable` .
The code is

```
SELECT Distinct s.SpecialID
FROM sample s, otherTable o
WHERE s.otherTableID = o.id
```

I would have written this as

```
SELECT Distinct s.SpecialID
FROM sample s
IF s.otherTableID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT s.specialID from SAMPLE s JOIN OTHERTABLE o ON(s.othertableID = o.id)`

Comment: What do you mean by that? @user207421

Comment: It was intended as a suggestion for rewriting the SQL query which forms the subject of your question. This seems rather obvious. Your way isn't equivalent.

Comment: @user207421 but isn't the point of a join to return the columns from several different tables in one table? This does not happen in my example, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using InnoDB, and have actually declared the foreign key relationship in the table schema, then it's not necessary to test that the foreign key exists. MySQL will enforce this requirement automatically. Your second version should then be equivalent, since any non-null value should exist in the master table.

But if you're using MyISAM, foreign key constraints are not enforced automatically. In this case, it may be necessary to perform the test explicitly with a join.

Comment: Ok, so might it be considered good practice to do this, because the underlying database may change?

Comment: No, I don't think it's common practice at all. Even without constraints, business logic in the application will usually prevent orphan records.